# Best practice to follow for comparing TCHAR Array with null character

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am checking for registry path and extracting value ,however when registry path is not found I had to check other locations

```
TCHAR Answer[MAX_PATH] = { L'\0' }; 
DWORD RegResult = SHRegGetPath(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Wow6432Node\key1"),  key, Answer, NULL);
```

This returns ERROR_SUCCESS if the key1 is present ,however I want to check other key if the key1 is present but has not given value

So I am thinking of comparing szAnswer with '\0' and proceed ahead

What would be the best practice to compare with '\0'

```
    if (!(_tcsicmp(Answer,TEXT("\0"))))
    {
        std::cout << "empty string" << std::endl;


    }
```

Comment: How are you reading the value? The return code from read function itself should help instead of comparing on the value.

Comment: You would be better off testing for a zero-length string: `if (!_tcslen(szAnswer)) …`

Comment: @wander3r Return code just gives success if key is found and if key has value it stores in szAnswer

Comment: The TCHAR stuff has been obsolete since the turn of the century. You might want a 21st century textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
if (!(_tcsicmp(Answer,TEXT("\0"))))
{
    std::cout << "empty string" << std::endl;


}
```

```
            or
```

Test for zero length string using

```
if (!_tcslen(szAnswer))
```